# I have trouble using color theme in eclipse neon.1

Tags: eclipse, macos, colors

I use eclipse neon.1 on a macbook and I cannot change the color theme 
I have installed the color theme from the marketplace but when I choose a theme from the appearance it cannot be seen in the small screen on the right and I cannot apply it.
I did the same job on my windows computer and it works just fine.
Thanks for your time!
(I want the oblivion color theme)

Comment: Have you tried another Eclipse version on your macbook? For example, Eclipse Mars, does it work? If it does it might be an issue with Neon and your OS that you could report.

Comment: I have changed color theme previously in two windows pcs with eclipse neon.1 with no problem at all. So I do not think it is a common issue of eclipse neon.1. Thanks for your reply!|

Comment: That it's not an issue in Windows it doesn't mean that it's not an issue in OSX, just saying.

Comment: I'm having the same type of problem on my macbook...have been since I upgraded OS and Eclipse...haven't been able to find a solution. I should add that, for me, the theme selector doesn't render correctly AND the theme resets everytime I restart Eclipse.